# Can we read/write to Reserved areas in /proc/iomem

Tags: linux, io, linux-kernel, x86, linux-device-driver

I have lot of areas in /proc/mem with "Reserved". Can we performed read/write on these areas.

```
$ sudo cat /proc/iomem 
00000000-00000fff : Reserved
00001000-0009e7ff : System RAM
0009e800-0009ffff : Reserved
```

Comment: Probably yes, but those areas are probably just backed by regular physical RAM.  And I wouldn't be surprised if Linux uses some of that space for the IDT or GDT; it's common to find the IDT at physical address `0`.  Of course, store/load instructions will use virtual addresses so you'd need to know the right virtual address for those physical addresses, e.g. in the range of addresses the Linux kernel uses to direct-map all of physical RAM.

Comment: @PeterCordes. OP posted an example, I bet there are big areas which represent PCI ECAM and other window resources for PCI root bridge, etc.

Comment: It's probably reserved for a reason and you shouldn't attempt to overwrite it. The Reserved region just below 000a0000 is probably the Extended BIOS Data Area (EBDA). It is probably used by System Management Mode (SMM) functions in the BIOS while the system is running, so it's not a good idea to overwrite it.